# Iterate filter object multiple times doesn't get correct value

Tags: python

The following code gets correct answer because `list()` is called before assigning to `b`. `max(b)` may get wrong value if removing `list`.

```
a = map(lambda x: (x[0]*10 + x[1], x[2]*10 + x[3]), aLongList)
b = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] < 24 and x[1] < 60, a)) # convert to a list
if not any(b):
    #.... omitted
max(b)
```

Is it a way to get the right result without creating a list (in case the list is huge)?

---

**Test:**

The following code

```
def perm(A):
    for i,x in enumerate(A):
        for j,y in enumerate(A):
            if i == j: continue
            for k,z in enumerate(A):
                if i == k or j == k: continue
                for l,a in enumerate(A):
                    if l == i or l == j or l == k: continue
                    yield [A[i], A[j], A[k], A[l]]

a = map(lambda x: (x[0]*10 + x[1], x[2]*10 + x[3]), perm([1,9,6,0]))
b = (filter(lambda x: x[0] < 24 and x[1] < 60, a)) # Removed list, so b is a filter obj instead of list

if not any(b):
    pass
max(b)
```

returns `(16, 9)` instead of `(19, 6)`.

Comment: `max(filter(lambda x: x[0] < 24 and x[1] < 60, a))` this worked for me gives `[19, 6]`

Comment: It needs to call both `any()` and `max()` on the filter object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.tee`.

> Return n independent iterators from a single iterable.

```
from itertools import tee

b1, b2 = tee(filter(lambda x: x[0] < 24 and x[1] < 60, a), 2)

if not any(b1):
    pass
max(b2)
```

Output:

```
(19, 6)
```